# Widgets Section not displaying in theme customizer

Tags: functions, widgets, theme-customizer

When in the WP Theme Customizer, my widget management section isn't displaying (i.e. I can't add/change/remove widgets). I CAN, however, add widgets from the Appearance -> Widgets section, just not in the customizer.

Also, the widgets themselves display perfectly in the customizer, just not the sidebar section to edit add/change/remove them.

Here's how I declare my widget area in my `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'mm_widgets_init' );

function mm_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Stories', 'mm' ),
        'id'            => 'mm-stories',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="item widget %2$s col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-md-4">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<div class="story-header">',
        'after_title'   => '</div>',
    ) );
}
```

And in case it's relevant, though I don't know why it would be, here's how I output the widget area on the site

```
<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'mm-stories' ) ) : 
endif; ?>
```

I've used this same code (with minor changes) on an older theme, and it works fine there, so I'm really not sure why it's not working here.

I know this is similar to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149236/widgets-not-displaying-in-theme-customizer), but the answer there suggests that I have to be on the page that calls that particular widget-area in order to see the widgets in the customizer. That answer doesn't work for me, though, because I'm already on the right page, and the actual widgets do in fact display correctly in the customizer.  However, I need to be able to edit them from the customizer as well, not just see them.

In other words, I can see the widgets fine both on the live site as well as in the customizer, but I can only EDIT them through the Appearance -> Widgets page in the admin.  I need to be able to edit them in the customizer as well.

I'm running the latest version of wordpress (4.1), and my one and only plugin (WPFront User Role Editor) is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that I de-registered jQuery in my `functions.php` file.  I re-registered the correct version of jQuery by calling `wp_register_script('jquery', ...)` and suddenly, everything worked perfectly.