# Widgets not working in Customizr but working in Appearance

Tags: customization, widgets, sidebar, theme-customizer

I'm having some trouble with my widgets. I've registered widget areas correctly; as the widgets are showing up in the "Appearance" menu. However widgets aren't showing up in the Customizr section of WP; getting this error:

*There are no widget areas currently rendered in the preview. Navigate in the preview to a template that makes use of a widget area in order to access its widgets here.*

I've tried the solutions mentioned here: [Widgets not displaying in theme customizer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149236/widgets-not-displaying-in-theme-customizer?newreg=29a8c1dd80004a61881e8db98e11490e) and here [Widgets Section not displaying in theme customizer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175685/widgets-section-not-displaying-in-theme-customizer) but had no luck.

My code is:

```
register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'Sidebar Widgets',
            'id' => 'sidebar-widgets',
            'before_widget' => '<section class="widget">',
            'after_widget' => '</section>',
            'before_title' => '<h4>',
            'after_title' => '</h4>'
        ));

<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-widgets' ) ) : ?>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-widgets'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Running WordPress 4.4.2.

I've tried the following things:
 1. Tried dynamic_sidebar in different templates (header, front-page, index).
 2. Tried navigating to different pages as suggested, no luck
 3. No console errors
 4. Tried theme on a different WordPress installation, no luck
 5. Tried another theme, widgets working

Any other code I can add to this question to help troubleshoot?

Comment: where/when do you register the sidebar? where do you display it?

Comment: any errors in the console? customizer is mostly javascript, if there is a conflict or error the widgets section may not load...

Comment: Are you *sure* [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172399/1685) is not your issue?

Comment: @MarkKaplun, I've tried it in the sidebar, front-page, even added it in the header. No luck.

Comment: @majick Nope no errors in the console

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Yep, first thing I tried. I've tried dynamic_sidebar on all different sections and pages, no luck.

Comment: @VernonJoyce, it is very unlikely that if you have the sidebar registration in the header you see it in admin at all..... so where do you have the registration that you see the sidebar in the admin but not in the costumizer?

Comment: @MarkKaplun in my sidebar. I have also tried it directly in index and front-page but no luck.

Comment: sidebar registration should be done in functions.php of a theme or file included from it

Comment: @MarkKaplun sorry mark didn't read properly. Registration is happening in functions.php and dynamic_sidebar is sidebar.php

Comment: and if you place a widget while in the admin side, do you see then the sidebar in the costumizer?

Comment: @MarkKaplun yep, shows up in the preview for both pages.

Comment: @VernonJoyce Apologies for resurrecting an old question, but did you ever get to the bottom of this? Just experiencing the same issue!

Comment: @MattWoodward nope unfortunately not. If you happen to create a new question for this please let me know, would love to follow in hopes of a solution.

Comment: @VernonJoyce Thanks for the quick response :) Have scoured around for a solution too but no joy at all. Exactly the same issue, working fine in Appearance > Widgets, but no options under the Customizer. Really bizarre!

Answer (score 2):

The customizer needs the sidebar to be "displayed" in order to detect its existence on the page. In your code you display the sidebar only if it is "active" which means that it has at least one widget in it, otherwise when no widgets are included it is not displayed and therefore the customizer can not detect it.

Don't check for sidebar "activity", the `display_sidebar` should output empty `div` or a like if no widgets exist in it so no real point in preventing its execution.

Comment: Thanks Mark, unfortunately removing the if statement did not solve my problem. Even if I call it just via <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-widgets'); ?> I still have no luck. It's still in Appearance but not in Customizer.