# Sidebar not show customizer!

Tags: widgets, theme-customizer

It's showing `widgets.php`:

[image]

Not showing customizer:

[image: not show customizer]

**sidebar.php**

```
function footer_sidebar()
{
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name' => __( 'Footer Sidebar 1', 'footer1' ), 
            'id' => 'footer1',
            'description' => __( 'Footer Sidebar 1', 'footer1' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div id="footer1" class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:-25px;">', 
            'after_widget' => '</div>', 
            'before_title' => '<h3>', 
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
        )
    );

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name' => __( 'Footer Sidebar 2', 'footer2' ), 
            'id' => 'footer2',
            'description' => __( 'Footer Sidebar 2', 'footer2' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div id="footer2" class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:-25px;">', 
            'after_widget' => '</div>', 
            'before_title' => '<h3>', 
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'footer_sidebar' );
```

**footer.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('footer1') ) : ?><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('footer2') ) : ?><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('footer3') ) : ?><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('footer4') ) : ?><?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172399/1685)?

Comment: Remember to add wp_head() before `</header>` tag and wp_footer() before `</body>` tag.
It works for but I had the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the function `footer_sidebar()` in the file functions.php not sidebar.php

Is the footer.php included on site you opened the customizer?

Comment: The IFs in footer.php are not needed as well, although that is probably not the reason for the fail.

Comment: functions.php:
`<?php require_once('inc/tool/customizer.php');
require_once('sidebar.php');
 ?>`
sidebar it's working  : http://prntscr.com/a2j8xl 
Sidebar not showing customizer!

Answer (score 0):

You might be forgotten to add wp_footer(); function before the closing body tag in your footer.php. That causes the javascript cannot finish its instruction in the customizer.